# Navbar toggle in Bootstrap 3 without using 'navbar-default' class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my navigation and footer links collapse into a toggle button when the width is decreased, but without making them have the class 'navbar-default' (that class adds another navigation bar to my navigation bar and makes it look ugly).

Here's an example of my header's navigation HTML:

```
<div class="header" id="header-container">
    <div class="container" id="header">

            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-collapse-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>


        <ul class="nav collapse navbar-collapse nav-pills pull-right" id="header-collapse-1">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/img/resume.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The navigation buttons disappear but no toggle button appears to open the accordion. Please let me know if there is a workaround to get the toggle button to appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only way i can think of is to add a class to the navbar and create a couple of rules to override navbars for elements *only with that class*.

Consider adding these 2 rules (and customize the styles as you need):-

```
.custom-nav-bar.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #ddd; /*Background color for holder*/
}
.custom-nav-bar.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888; /*Background color for bar in the holder*/
}
```

and add `custom-nav-bar` to the `navbar-toggle` element

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left custom-nav-bar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-collapse-1">
```

```css
.custom-nav-bar.navbar-toggle {
   background-color: #ddd;
}
.custom-nav-bar.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header" id="header-container">
    <div class="container" id="header">
    
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left custom-nav-bar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
   

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills pull-left " >
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/img/resume.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
         </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to however work on the menu items to be displayed vertically.

Comment: Thank you for the help! In order to make the TITLE stay on the left right after the `<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed..."...>...</button>` tags I placed a `<a href="#" id="header-brand-custom"...>TITLE</a>` tag and it stays perfectly on the left even on collapse.

Thanks again!